# Conditional rendering after fetch in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, conditional-rendering

How to do conditional rendering after fetch in react native?I wan't to render components after
1.Successful fetch with the `responseData`
2.Network request fails
3.If there is empty `responseData` returned from server

For now I'm displaying only the successful result.I want to display the failure case also.How do I render `Text` component after unsuccessful fetch.Following is my code

```
  onPressSubmit() {

    fetch("xxxx", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        url: this.state.url
      })
    })
     .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) =>
    {
            this.setState({
            res:responseData.message,
            showLoading: false
                    }, () => console.log(this.state.res));
        }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
  renderArticle(){
      const {title} = this.state.res;
      const {image} = this.state.res;
      const {text} = this.state.res;
      const {id} = this.state.res;
      const {author} =this.state.res;
      const {html} = this.state.res;


              return (
           <TouchableOpacity 
            onPress={() => Actions.addNewarticle({heading:title, authorname:author, description:text, htmlcon:html})}
          >
            <CardSection>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <Image
                  source={{ uri:image }}
                  style={styles.thumbnail_style}
                />
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{title}</Text>
              </View>
            </CardSection>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          ); 
  }
render(){
return(
 <View>
{this.renderArticle()}
 </View>
);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `renderNetworkFailure` method in which you can display whatever you want. Into `render` method. check your response data is available or not? I have check blank string.

```
render(){
const isResponseData = (this.state.res == '') ? this.renderNetworkFailure() : this.renderArticle()
return(
 <View>
{isResponseData}
 </View>
);
```

Comment: Can I give one more condition that if `responseData` is empty?

Comment: Why not? It's up to your requirement.

Comment: So how would that be? Could you please check this `const isResponseData = (this.state.res == '') ? this.renderNetworkFailure() : this.renderArticle() :this.renderEmptyData()`

Comment: No its an ternary operator. its like if else. `?` is `if` and `:` is `else`

Answer (score 0):

I think more precisely this is how your answer would look like, and if you want to show for the network failure as well then you must keep a state variable for it also.(Im also a beginner in react-native please correct if there is anything wrong)

```
render(){
return(
<View>
{(this.state.err)?this.networkFailure():({this.state.res.length? this.renderArticle():this.renderNothing()})}
</View>
)
}
```